# Excluir productos repetidos Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo una tabla donde guardo los productos favoritos que se guardan los visitantes:

**Mi tabla `likes`**

| id | entrie_id | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 33 | 1 |

Luego tengo otra base de datos donde almaceno las búsquedas guardadas de los clientes 
 **Mi tabla `busquedas`**:

| id | user_id | etiqueta_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 4 |

**Mi tabla `productos`**:

| id | name | etiqueta_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | producto_1 | 3 |
| 2 | producto_2 | 3 |

La idea es que en una vista tengo que obtener los favoritos guardados y seguido los productos que corresponden a esa búsqueda guardada.

Para ver los favoritos lo realizo así:

Controlador:

```
$mislikes = Like::with('producto')->select('entrie_id')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

Modelo:

```
public function producto()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Productos::class, 'id', 'entrie_id');
    }
```

Y luego en la vista:

```
@foreach ($mislikes as $item)
  @foreach ($item->producto as $articulos)
    ....
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

---

Para obtener los productos que corresponden a las etiquetas guardadas hago lo siguiente:

Controlador:

```
$misBusquedas = Busquedas::with('producto')->select('etiqueta_id')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

Modelo:

```
public function producto()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Productos::class, 'etiqueta_id', 'etiqueta_id');
    }
```

Y luego en la vista:

```
@foreach ($misBusquedas as $busq)
  @foreach ($busq->producto as $busqueda)
    ....
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Esto de momento me funciona, pero claro puede dar el caso que tengo guardado un favorito que también están guardado como una búsqueda, se puede hacer un `whereNotIn` de algún modo para excluir los que ya están en favoritos??

---

**Mi solución con un `JOIN`**

```
$mislikes = Like::with('producto')->select('entrie_id')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();

 $ids_array = $mislikes->pluck('entrie_id')->toArray();

 $misBusquedas = Productos::join('busquedas', 'productos.etiqueta_id', '=', 'busquedas.etiqueta_id')
                    ->where('busquedas.user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                    ->select('productos.*')
                    ->whereNotIn('productos.id', $mislikes->pluck('entrie_id')->toArray())->get();
```

Comment: Está rara la relación `producto` en el modelo `Like`. ¿Por qué `hasMany` y no `belongsTo`? Tendría más sentido que cada Like corresponda a un único Producto. Además quien guarda la fk es Like y no Producto, por lo que correspondería `belongsTo` como relación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurre que si lo que quieres finalmente son los productos para mostrar en una vista, podrías definir las relaciones en el modelo `Producto` y hacer las consultas a BD desde ese modelo.
Ej:

Modelo Producto

```php
/*
* Los likes que tiene cada producto (por cualquier usuario) 
*/
public function likes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Like::class, 'id', 'entrie_id');
}

/*
* Las busquedas que tiene cada producto (por cualquier usuario) 
*/
public function busquedas()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Busqueda::class, 'etiqueta_id', 'etiqueta_id');
}
```

Consultas

```php
// los Producto que tengan likes del usuario autenticado
$mislikes = Producto::whereHas('likes', function ($query) {
        $query->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
    })
    ->get();
// los Producto que tengan busquedas del usuario autenticado
$misBusquedas = Producto::whereHas('busquedas', function ($query) {
        $query->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
    })
    ->get();
```

Vista

```
@foreach ($mislikes as $producto)
    //...
@endforeach

@foreach ($misBusquedas as $producto)
    //...
@endforeach
```

Como mencionas, para que no se repitan los productos puedes usar `whereNotIn`, al cual tendrás que pasarle un array con los valores de la columna `id` a consultar:

```php
->whereNotIn('id', $ids_array)
```

Puedes obtener todas la `id` de los productos que ya están en la colección `$mislikes` con `pluck()` y convertirla a un array con el método `toArray()`:

```php
$ids_array = $mislikes->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

Finalmente la consulta quedaría:

```php
$misBusquedas = Producto::whereHas('busquedas', function ($query) {
        $query->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
    })
    ->whereNotIn('id', $mislikes->pluck('id')->toArray())
//    ->withCount('busquedas')
//    ->orderBy('busquedas_count', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Hola @porloscerros Ψ me devuelve este error `App\Http\Controllers\Web::App\Http\Controllers\{closure}(): Argument #1 ($query) must be of type App\Http\Controllers\Builder, Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder given, called in /var/www/juanda/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php on line 1199`

Comment: Es que creo que has tomado `etiqueta_id` como el id del producto y la etiqueta es una subcategoria

Comment: Voy a poner una respuesta al final de mi pregunta con un `JOIN` , de este modo esta funcionando, pero me gustaria saber hacerlo con los modelos.

Comment: Por el error, puedes pasarle directamente la variable, si typearla `'likes', function ($query)` y `'likes', function ($query)`, o importar la clase `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`. Edité la respuesta

Comment: Dale, agrega tu solución en una respuesta, y queda esta como alternativa

Comment: He publicado mi solución pero pongo la tuya como correcta, me parece más apropiada, gracias!

Answer (score 1):

**Mi solución con un `JOIN`**

```
$mislikes = Like::with('producto')->select('entrie_id')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();

 $ids_array = $mislikes->pluck('entrie_id')->toArray();

 $misBusquedas = Productos::join('busquedas', 'productos.etiqueta_id', '=', 'busquedas.etiqueta_id')
                    ->where('busquedas.user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                    ->select('productos.*')
                    ->whereNotIn('productos.id', $mislikes->pluck('entrie_id')->toArray())->get();
```